# Realm Data Connector with Heroku Postgres: must be superuser or replication role to use replication slots

Tags: postgresql, heroku, realm, heroku-postgres

I'm following **Realm Postgres Connector** reference for syncing our Realm database with our Heroku PostgreSQL database: https://docs.realm.io/platform/using-synced-realms/server-side-usage/data-integration/postgres-connector#realm-data-adapter

It's working fine locally as I could connect to the PG local database with`superuser` role in order to use replication slots. However, `superuser` or `replication` roles cannot be set on Heroku PostgreSQL database, hence leading to the following PG error:

`PGRES_FATAL_ERROR: ERROR: must be superuser or replication role to use replication slots`

Does anybody already got Realm Postgres Connector working with a Heroku PG database? Or could think of a workaround?

Thanks for your help!

Lucas

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/hasura/realm-pg-sync. It works with Postgres on Hasura and was made by a colleague.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the resource! I've found the same and it looks very promising. However we've already migrated to Amazon RDS and we don't consider migrating again for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku support confirmed that there is currently no way to use `replication` roles:

> Unfortunately, we do not allow creation of new replication slots by customers, as replication users are very privileged in Postgres, almost to the superuser level.

Hence I've decided to migrate to Amazon RDS. Here is a great article on how to perform such migration: https://www.lewagon.com/fr/blog/how-to-migrate-your-heroku-postgres-database-to-amazon-rds

Comment: Good guide, but it is not going to work for a big production database.